# Why should there be a gas in a cathode ray tube?

Tags: electrons, gas

Is it necessary to have a gas in a cathode ray tube? Why?

Comment: do you mean CRT as in the display (like an old TV)? There are a LOT of different kinds of "tubes" that use "cathode rays", and some may need a slight amount of gas for one reason or another, but mostly you'd like a really good vacuum. When you say "Why should there be...?" it suggests you heard or read somewhere that there "should" be. Can you add some more information where this is coming from? *Thanks!*

Comment: Hydrogen is not usually used for much of anything, not least because it rapidly diffuses out.